# How to prove bijective continuous functions $(\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n)$ map open-in-$\mathbb{R}^n$ sets to open-in-$\mathbb{R}^n$ sets ？

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

How to prove bijective continuous functions $(\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n)$ map open-in-$\mathbb{R}^n$ sets to open-in-$\mathbb{R}^n$ sets？

For example, an bijective continuous functions $F:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, it map closed-in-$\mathbb{R}^n$ set $A$ to closed-in-$\mathbb{R}^n$ set $B$. $A_1$ is an open-in-$\mathbb{R}^n$ set included in $A$. $A_1$'s inverse image is $B_1$. I know that an open set's inverse image is an open set，but the openness is relative, that means $B_1$ is open in $B$, but how to prove $B_1$ is also open in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: This is invariance of domain and highly non-trivial. There *is* no simple proof of this fact.

Comment: This requires heavy machinery from Algebraic Topology.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy you can prove this without any algebraic topology (as Brouwer did when he first proved this) but it can also be done using dimension theory plus Brouwer fixed point theorem. The latter has a purely combinatorial proof.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks for all the information.